# How to compare fields (possibly arrays) in SQL queries in an unordered way?

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison, unordered

Let's say you have a database with data about a game with teams of 2 players. There's a `team` table with `player_id` fields and a `win` field (0 for a loss, 1 for a win), and a `player` table with an `id` and `weapon` field.

You want to know the team's win rate of combinations of weapons the 2 players are using.

The important thing here is that it doesn't matter which player is using which weapon. So we want to compare the weapons of the players in an unordered way.

You could also use an `players` array field in the team table but that approach comes with the same problem I think.

Ideally I'd want to write something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(t.win) AS win_fraction, weapon1, weapon2
FROM team t
JOIN player p1 ON t.player_id1 = p1.id
JOIN player p2 ON t.player_id2 = p2.id
GROUP BY UNORDERED(p1.weapon, p2.weapon) AS (weapon1, weapon2)
```

Obviously, the `UNORDERED` keyword is not part of SQL but I think the syntax here makes it sufficiently clear that this is the wanted result:

```
| win_fraction | weapon1 | weapon2 |
|--------------|---------|---------|
| 0.63         | AK_47   | P90     |
| 0.75         | AK_47   | AK_47   |
| 0.22         | P90     | P90     |
```

Notice that there shouldn't be a row with `P90` as `weapon1` and `AK_47` as `weapon2` unless it returns exactly the same `win_fraction` as the row with these weapons in the reversed order (thus the ordering of the weapons shouldn't affect the calculated win_fraction).

Has anyone come across the same problem? And if so, how did you manage to solve it?

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The solution needs to be general enough to have X players. A specific solution to the 2 player problem case like using `LEAST` and `GREATEST` doesn't work in the 3 player problem case as we'd also need to have a `MIDDLE` keyword:

```
SELECT AVG(t.win) AS win_fraction
FROM team t
JOIN player p1 ON t.player_id1 = p1.id
JOIN player p2 ON t.player_id2 = p2.id
JOIN player p3 ON t.player_id3 = p3.id
GROUP BY
    LEAST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon),
    MIDDLE(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon),
    GREATEST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon);`
```

Comment: Please make your question complete by a) adding sample table data and then b) showing us what the output of your query should be.

Comment: Agreed, I added some further clarifications.

Comment: I edited my answer to cover your new requirements.  Note that further changes to your question may draw downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You may aggregate using the `LEAST` and `GREATEST` scalar functions:

```
SELECT AVG(t.win) AS win_fraction
FROM team t
INNER JOIN player p1
    ON t.player_id1 = p1.id
INNER JOIN player p2
    ON t.player_id2 = p2.id
GROUP BY
    LEAST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon),
    GREATEST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon);
```

Note that you might want to also include the `GROUP BY` clause in your select, depending on the output you expect.

For grouping by three weapons, we can try:

```
SELECT AVG(t.win) AS win_fraction
FROM team t
INNER JOIN player p1
    ON t.player_id1 = p1.id
INNER JOIN player p2
    ON t.player_id2 = p2.id
GROUP BY
    LEAST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon),
    CASE WHEN p1.weapon <> LEAST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon) AND
              p1.weapon <> GREATEST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon)
         THEN p1.weapon
         WHEN p2.weapon <> LEAST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon) AND
              p2.weapon <> GREATEST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon)
         THEN p2.weapon
         ELSE p3.weapon END,
    GREATEST(p1.weapon, p2.weapon, p3.weapon);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm wondering if that would work if you'd have more than 2 players?

Comment: I don't know, why don't you try it?  By the way, you never gave any sample data, so I can't test anything.

Comment: I know, but the problem just needs a more general solution I feel. If we'd have three players, this wouldn't work anymore as we'd need to have a `MIDDLE` keyword as well (see edit of the post).

Comment: @HansCauwenbergh Please _don't_ change your question after others have answered, as it is rude.  I have edited my answer, but further changes to your question will probably attract my downvote.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just didn't want to overload you with (to me) irrelevant details. Thing is, this also doesn't work for more than 3 players.